# Pair of die and probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A pair of dice is loaded. The probability that a 2 appears on the first
die is 3/13 and the probability that a 4 appears on the second die is
3/13. Other outcomes for each die appear with probability 2/13. What
is the probability of 6 appearing as the sum of the numbers when the
two dice are rolled?

Answer (score 4):

Add up the following:

- Probability of $1$ on 1st dice and $5$ on 2nd dice: $\frac{2}{13}\cdot\frac{2}{13}$
- Probability of $2$ on 1st dice and $4$ on 2nd dice: $\frac{3}{13}\cdot\frac{3}{13}$
- Probability of $3$ on 1st dice and $3$ on 2nd dice: $\frac{2}{13}\cdot\frac{2}{13}$
- Probability of $4$ on 1st dice and $2$ on 2nd dice: $\frac{2}{13}\cdot\frac{2}{13}$
- Probability of $5$ on 1st dice and $1$ on 2nd dice: $\frac{2}{13}\cdot\frac{2}{13}$

And you get $\frac{25}{169}$

Comment: I don't want to edit the question at this point, but the word "dice" should be replaced with "die" (I guess I didn't know the difference at the time).

Answer (score 1):

If $P(a)P(b)$ represents $a$ appearing in the first dice, $b$ in the second,

$$P(1)P(5)+P(2)P(4)+P(3)P(3)+P(4)P(2)+P(5)P(1)$$

$$=\frac2{13}\cdot\frac2{13}+\frac3{13}\cdot\frac3{13}+\frac2{13}\cdot\frac2{13}+\frac2{13}\cdot\frac2{13}+\frac2{13}\cdot\frac2{13}$$

$$=\frac9{169}+4\cdot\frac4{169}$$